# Understanding the interpretation of array labels

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

The following program demonstrates a somewhat surprising fact that many people may not be aware of.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char[]);

int main(void) {
  char array[] = {0};
  printf("[Control]  (&array[0]: %p)\n", &array[0]);
  printf("[Local]    (array: %p) (&array: %p)\n", array, &array);
  test(array);
}

void test(char array[]) {
  printf("[Function] (array: %p) (&array: %p)\n", array, &array);
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -o test test.c && ./test
```

Output:

```
[Control]  (&array[0]: 0x5b49a21cf4e6)
[Local]    (array: 0x5b49a21cf4e6) (&array: 0x5b49a21cf4e6)
[Function] (array: 0x5b49a21cf4e6) (&array: 0x63f81d8e4950)
```

The label for an array is apparently treated differently depending on whether it is the name of a variable passed to a function versus when it is referring to a local variable. In the case of the locally declared array, the expressions "array", "&array", and "&array[0]" yield precisely identical addresses. Whereas within a function the label does not resolve the same way.

Why is that?

Comment: Make a choice between "C" and "C++". In C++ your test function would look something like `void test(const std::string_view)` or `void test(const std::string&)` and all the array to pointer stuff would not be recommended (and neither would printf be used but std::format/std::cout)

Comment: This is because you cannot pass an array to a function. Instead a pointer to the first element is passed. In your example `void test(char[]);` is the same as `void test(char*);` This does not only have an effect on the address operator, but also on the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: The call `test(array)` is the same as `test(&array[0])`.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since there's nothing related to C++ as such in the question.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of [What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay). You do realize that `array` in the function parameter list is "adjusted" into a pointer to the first element, yeah? And that pointer is passed on the stack. It points to the original array, but the pointer itself is a variable of its own.

Comment: "many people may not be aware of." This should be explained in any decent beginners book when functions and passing of parameters is addressed.

Comment: The tl;dr: there are two different rules in informally called "array decay". Rule 1 is that an array, whenever used in most expressions, gets replaced by a pointer to the first element of that array. This is what happens in main(). Rule 2 is that any array part of a function parameter list gets silently adjusted by the compiler to a pointer to the first element of that array. These 2 rules correspond and are compatible so they are often bunched together into what we call "array decay".

Comment: So your function is really `void test(char* array)`, where `array` is a pointer variable allocated at an address of its own, holding the address of the array in main. When you type `&array` inside the function, you get the address of that local pointer variable. But when you type `&array` in main(), you actually encounter one of the few cases where an array doesn't decay - when the `&` operator is applied. So the result of `&array` in main is a pointer to array, `char (*)[1]` in this case. But still this will hold the same address as the array, and as the first item too.

Comment: @Lundin: That was precisely the root of my confusion. The aliasing of &array and &array[0] for local variables now makes complete sense. Thank you!